# Is there anyway to control which login workbench uses when logged into multiple orgs?

Tags: login, workbench

I'm almost always have logged in to more than one org in the last half hour.  When I launch workbench and click login, it always seems to pick the session for the org I do not want.  I click logout from workbench and then login and it picks the wrong org again.

Is there anyway to force it to use a certain login?  Or way to force the org I don't want to logout and stay logged out?

I really do not want to shut my browser down or leave the org that I do want to work in.  Or flush my entire browser cache and lose my whole context.

Comment: There should be a "use a different login" or "this is not me" link on the popup page you get to authenticate. Is that not present?

Comment: There is no popup if I have had sessions logged in recently with the browser I'm in.  I do not get the "Choose a Username" dialog or any other.  The scenerio is--

Log into Org A.
Log into Org B.
Close tab with Org B session.
Go to workbench in new tab.
CLick Login.

At this point, I get Org B, not org A.  I hit the logout but in workbench and start workbench over and still end up in Org B.